# Python less than not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Made a small script for my raspberry pi to toggle a fan once the cpu temperature reaches a certain point, the code is:

```
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
R = 7
GPIO.setup(R, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(R, GPIO.HIGH)
while True:
    def getCPUtemperature():
        res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
        return res.replace("temp=", "").replace("'C\n", "")
    CPU = getCPUtemperature()
    print(CPU)
    if CPU > 36.0:
        GPIO.output(R, GPIO.LOW)
    elif CPU < 30.0:
        GPIO.output(R, GPIO.HIGH)
```

First of all, yes I am using a relay so high and low are supposed to be like this.
The works but the problem is that despite the console outputting values like 29.3, the fan still runs and the program still thinks the value is higher than 36, I have no idea why it doesn't realise that the value is smaller than 27

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

thanks

Comment: Anthony's answer below is correct. I thought it worth noting that under Python 3, `'29.9' < 30.0` results in an exception `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()`. There are plenty of good reasons to upgrade Python especially if you are just starting out.

Answer (score 2):

The value returned from `getCPUtemperature` looks like it should be converted to a float, e.g:

```
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    return float(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
```